# Como agregar elementos a un array en javascript continuando la numeración

Tags: javascript

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo un elemento **input File múltiple**, cada vez que se carga una imagen se activa una función que recorre los elementos cargados y los agrega a un array. Todo funciona bien, pero si vuelvo a cargar imágenes, la numeración que se le asigna (Imagen 0,Imagen 1.....,n) vuelve al comienzo y me gustaría que se agregaran las nuevas filas del array a partir del numero de la ultima fila agregada, es posible esto ?

```
const base64Image = new Array();
const imagenesDescripcion = new FormData();

function insertImage(){
    let imagenes = document.querySelector('input[name="files"]');       
    if(imagenes.files){
        let file = imagenes.files;
        for(let i = 0;i < file.length;i++){
            imagenesDescripcion.append('imagenesDescripcion['+i+']', file[i]);
            let nombre = file[i].name
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
            reader.onload = function() {
                let image = new Image();
                image.src = reader.result;
                image.onload = function(){
                    $ ('#summernote').summernote('insertNode',this);
                    base64Image.push({"Imagen": i, "Img": this['currentSrc'],'Nombre':nombre})
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(base64Image);

}
```

El console.log

```
0: {Imagen: 1, Img: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RMWRXhpZgAAT', Nombre: 'producto12.jpg'}
1: {Imagen: 0, Img: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RM7RXhpZgAAT', Nombre: 'producto11.jpg'}
2: {Imagen: 2, Img: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RLFRXhpZgAAT', Nombre: 'producto13.jpg'}
3: {Imagen: 0, Img: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RMWRXhpZgA', Nombre: 'producto12.jpg'}
4: {Imagen: 1, Img: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RLFRXhpZgAA', Nombre: 'producto13.jpg'}
```

Comment: base64Image es tu array, usalo en el I for(let i = base64Image.lenght ;i < file.length + base64Image.lenght ;i++), esa es la mas facil y rapida que se me ocurre, la otra es refactorizar todo y hacerlo mas performante, pero con eso solucionas tu pregunta.

Comment: quieres que empieza cada vez con el último numero en vez de 0?

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas el número?

Comment: Exacto necesito que comience con el ultimo numero, ya que Al ser Imagen 0,Imagen 1, etc, al ser unido con otra variable lo utilizo para realizar algunas validaciones posteriormente en PH, pero si el numero se repite no funciona

Answer (score 0):

como te comentaba, podes usar base64image.lenght para referite al proximo id numerico, aca te dejo una pequeña modificación de tu codigo, no puedo probarlo pues me falta mucho contexto, pero miralo y comenta.

Saludos.

```js
const base64Image = new Array();
const imagenesDescripcion = new FormData();

function insertImage() {
  let files = [...document.querySelector('input[name="files"]').files];
  files && files.forEach((file, index) => {
    imagenesDescripcion.append(`imagenesDescripcion[${index}]`, file);

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = function() {
      let image = new Image();
      image.src = reader.result;

      image.onload = function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote('insertNode', this);
        base64Image.push({
          "Imagen": base64Image.length,
          "Img": this['currentSrc'],
          'Nombre': file.name
        })

      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: si quisiera aplicar lo mismo para imagenesDescripcion que es un FormData, como debería hacerlo, ya que si pongo base64Image.lenght en vez de index, aparace todo en 0

Comment: imagenesDescripcion.append(`imagenesDescripcion[${base64Image.length}]`, file); a esto te referis?

Comment: sii a eso mismo, ya que igual necesito que parta con el ultimo numero  y si pongo eso que me mencionas, devuelve 0 en todas las entradas y no va aumentando

Comment: Fijate que escribiste mal base64Image.lenght o hace todo en el onload de la imagen.